# How to compare 2 strings if one string is plain and second contains some html tags

Tags: string, match

I have some line of statements in my database.Whenever I create an article and add any line of these statements in this article manually then I have to find these lines and make them link.
problem is that I am using ckeditor for article posting and user can add style to text also. So I have to maintain style of matched line and also make that link.

statements (saved in a table):

1: this is first line
2: this is second line
3: this is third line

Article to be created :

```
this is my article , this is <span style="color:red">first</span> line. rest of article.
```

Now when user add this article then (1) line should be matched and in article it should be appear as :

```
<a href="dfa">this is <span style=".">first</span> line</a>
```

Hope I stated my problem clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to escape your strings from html tags someway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pattern for this is :

```
$pattern = "/(<?.*>)?this(<\/?.*>)? (<?.*>)?is(<\/?.*>)? (<?.*>)?first(<\/?.*>)? (<?.*>)?line(<\/?.*>)?;

preg_match_all($pattern,$str,$matches);
$replacement="<a href='#'>".$matches[0][0]."</a>";
$str = preg_replace($pattern,$replacement,$str,-1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
string mysql_real_escape_string ( string $unescaped_string [, resource $link_identifier ] )
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but I don't want to escape these tags. My requirement is that if an article contains any statement (saved in database) then this line should be convert into a link with preserving all style tag added to it.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the html tags. Then compare. You can use the following javascript to remove.

```
public static String html2text(String html) {
    return Jsoup.parse(html).text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With PHP, this should get you started:

```
$string_without_tags = strip_tags($string_with_tags);
```

[PHP.net strip_tags Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

Comment: No I cant strip tags because i need to prevent styles.